# String fails to match by and or, by "in" search

Tags: python, regex

String fails to match by and or, in search. Why?

```
string = 'This is some text with an email add: myusername@domain.com'
a = re.findall('[\w]+@[\w]+\.[\w]{3}',string)
b = string.split(' ')
print (a)
print (b)

if a==b:
    # also tried: if a in b:
    print(a, ' yes it is found')
else:
    print('not !?!?!')
```

```
['myusername@domain.com']
['This', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'with', 'an', 'email', 'add:', 'myusername@domain.com']
not !?!?!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` and `b` are both lists. They are not equal. And `a` is not an element of `b`. `b` contains only strings, not lists.

If you want to check if the single string contained in `a` is also contained in `b`, you can do this:

```
if a[0] in b:
    print("Yes, a[0] is in b")
```

In general, if you want to check if any element of one list is contained in another list, there are various ways to do it, but here is one:

```
if any(element in b for element in a):
    print("Some element of a is in b")
```

Comment: Ok. thank you. I didn't know splitting returns a list even for a single object.

Comment: You can tell it's a list because of the `[` `]` shown when you printed it out.

Comment: Yep. and also that rgex returns a list of a single object. I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Well a doesn't equal to b so it will never make it inside the if statement, you should loop over one list and compare it's elements to the other list as follow

```
import re

string = 'This is some text with an email add: myusername@domain.com'
a = re.findall('[\w]+@[\w]+\.[\w]{3}',string)
b = string.split(' ')
print (a)
print (b)

for aa in a:
    if aa in b: # tried
        print(a, ' yes it is found')
else:
    print('not !?!?!')
```